# Route component using navLInk react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to route a link and pass data.
the problem is when I receive it on news component, all the things i pass it to return an undefined..

app.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path="/news" component={News} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

parent.js

```
          <NavLink to={{
            pathname: '/news',
            state : { all : this.props.content} // this is what I want to send and I receive it from another
          }}>Todo</NavLink>
```

news.js

```
export default class News extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
}

render(){
    const foo = this.props.location.state
    console.log(foo) // Cannot read property 'state' of undefined..
    console.log(this.props.location) // return undefined
    console.log(this.props) // return empty {}

    return (

        <div className='container'>
                   <section>
                       <h1>hello world </h1>
                   </section>
       </div>

   )
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where `parent.js` lives in your site structure. But I've done a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jp4qr3q3ww?autoresize=1&expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14) for you.

I have defined a defaultProp in `parent.js` so some data is passed to the `NavLink` but you should be able to restructure the example for your needs.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jp4qr3q3ww?autoresize=1&expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14

app.js (index.js)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import News from "./news.js";
import Parent from "./parent.js";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" component={Parent} />
      <Route path="/news" component={News} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

parent.js

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Parent = props => (
  <NavLink
    to={{
      pathname: "/news",
      state: { all: props.content } // this is what I want to send and I receive it from another
    }}
  >
    Todo
  </NavLink>
);

Parent.defaultProps = {
  content: "some content"
};

export default Parent;
```

news.js

```
import React from "react";

export default class News extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const foo = this.props.location.state;
    console.log(foo); // Cannot read property 'state' of undefined..
    console.log(this.props.location); // return undefined
    console.log(this.props); // return empty {}

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <section>
          <h1>hello world </h1>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks to everyone, i try it but it dosen t work.. i think is for my app structure: 
app.js : `<Route path="/"  exact render={(props) => <Home {...props} content={this.state.content}  />}/>
<Route path="/news" component={News} />`

inside home component it is: 
`<parentComponent/>`
and parentComponent has the link to news, 
sorry for not clarifying it at the beginning

Comment: @Pil I've updated the codesandbox example with your feedback https://codesandbox.io/s/jp4qr3q3ww?autoresize=1&expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14

Comment: @Pil ah the `<parentComponent />` inside of `<Home />` needs you to pass the props to it.


`const Home = ({ content }) => <Parent content={content} />;`

Comment: thanks andy!!! i m pretty sure that im missing something.. here i edited the codesandbox.. [https://codesandbox.io/embed/v0z9381lzy] the return in news still {} :/

Comment: @Pil I've fixed the issue in your codesandbox. Had some ESLint errors and you had the `defaultProps` set wrong.

https://codesandbox.io/s/w0787jp3n5

Comment: If you are going directly to the URL `/news` then the `content` prop will be empty. It will only have a state when a user navigates / clicks the `<NavLink>` in parent

Comment: thanks Andy, still empty.. i dont understand your last comment.. i navigates via navLink on my "othercomponent".. why it does not work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191186/discussion-between-andykenward-and-pil).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your app is structured your `News` component may not be receiving router props. Try declaring your `Route` as follows:

```
<Route
    path="/news"
    render={routerProps => <News {...routerProps}/>}
/>
```

---

Alternatively, you may want to try using `withRouter`:

> You can get access to the `history` object's properties and the closest `<Route>`'s `match` via the `withRouter` higher-order component. `withRouter` will pass updated `match`, `location`, and `history` props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class News extends React.Component {
    ...
}

export default withRouter(News);
```